# Rails configure Timezone from YML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, timezone

I have a Rails 3.2.x app with my default timezone set in `application.rb` as `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`

I will be spinning up new servers in other timezones and need to figure out how to read the timezone configuration from a company.yml file where I set certain company attributes while still using the same github repo for ease of management.

For each server I have the following file in `config/initializers/company.rb`

```
default_company = {
    company_name: "changeme",
    company_phone: "000-000-0000",
    company_email: "default_email@example.net",
    logo_path: "public/logo_changeme.png",
    no_reply_email: "noreply@example.com"
}

file_name = Rails.root.join('config', 'company.yml')
Company = default_company.merge(YAML.load_file(file_name))
```

Then I have a `company.yml` file which contains the specific settings for each server instance which I call through the app:

```
:company_name: 'John's Company'
:company_phone: '281-314-0000'
:logo_path: 'public/logo.png'
:company_email: 'company@example.net'
:no_reply_email: 'noreply@example.com'
```

I want to be able to set a timezone configuration from the company.yml file or some configuration file so I can keep my github repo static.  I tried the following

`company.yml`

```
:company_name: 'John's Company'
:company_phone: '281-314-0000'
:logo_path: 'public/logo.png'
:company_email: 'company@example.net'
:no_reply_email: 'noreply@example.com'
:company_timezone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

And in my `config/application.rb` file I attempted the following:

`config.time_zone = Company[:company_timezone]`

But when I start my server I get:
`Invalid Timezone: Company[:company_timezone] (ArgumentError)`

So I tried the following in `config/application.rb`:
`config.time_zone = "#{Company[:company_timezone]}"`

When I start the server I get `uninitialized constant Myapp::Application::Company (NameError)`

So my question is, how can I use a company.yml file for each server in different timezones to set the `config/application.rb` timezone?  Do I have syntax errors?  Or is there another way to set the timezone from a configuration file into `application.rb`?

My only other thought is to create multiple git/github repos one for each instance and manually set the timezone in `application.rb`.  That will create a nightmare of having to keep multiple repos going for the same app.

If my question and description is not clear, please let me know.  To summarize, I'm trying to set `config.time_zone` dynamically from a `company.yml` file that is loaded with an initializer.  But I seem to be hitting a wall.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer or ideas you may have.

Comment: Also, I didn't think of this, but maybe the timezone can be an ENV variable set on the server which I can call from within `config/application.rb`?

Comment: My only other thought is to manually set the timezone in `config/application.rb` after each deploy.  Pain in the rear, but I could still keep my github repo static for each server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

So in my `application.rb` file I require `yaml` and load the `company.yml` file like so

**application.rb excerpt**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'yaml'  
Company = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../company.yml', __FILE__)))  
require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
     config.time_zone = "#{Company[:company_timezone]}"
```

However, when I spin up my server I receive the following error:

`config/initializers/company.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant Company`

So since I'm loading the `company.yml file in`application.rb`would I need to remove the`config/initializers/company.rb` ?

Comment: Yes, you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

application.rb is loaded before code in config/initializers. If you're going to load company.yml in application.rb, then you should remove the initializer in config/initializers.

Comment: Got it.  I removed `config/initalizers/company.rb` and loaded `company.yml` inside of `application.rb` as I posted in my answer.  So far everything works well in staging, time to push to production.