# Is it possible to call TIme.zone in settings.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I am using gem config for settings and I have a setting in my settings.yml 
like following.

```
default_year : <%= Time.now.year + 1 %>
```

but if I use

```
default_year : <%= Time.zone.now.year + 1 %>
```

it gives an error.

How do I use zone in my settings file ?

Following error on server startup
undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Not sure why I can't do Time.zone.now while I can do Time.now.in_time_zone in settings.yml

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Looks like different duplicated question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689476/rails-configure-timezone-from-yml-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails configure Timezone from YML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689476/rails-configure-timezone-from-yml-file)